# How to resolve the dependencies in Prism + DryIoC

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I am using ***Prism.DryIoc.Forms (7.1.0.431)*** in one of my ***Xamarin.Forms (4.0.0.497661)*** projects. I am facing issue while resolving the dependency in other service classes.

**Use case:**

We have a service called RestService which takes care of network calls and we have implemented one more service called ProfileService in which we get the user information and other stuff related to Profile's service. I am thinking to resolve the RestService dependency in  ProfileService to make the network calls.

I have registered both the services in `App.xaml.cs` under `RegisterTypes()` method.

Comment: can you provide us your code , to see how do you register and resolve your interface ?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to access the underlying container used by Prism.Forms. In your case DryIoc, you can easily get inside RegisterTypes method.

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
   containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
   AppContainer = containerRegistry.GetContainer(); //Assigning actual dryioc container
}
```

AppContainer is an property declared in App.xaml.cs class like below.

> Note:- GetContainer method is an extension method which is available
>   in Prism.DryIoc namespace. Import namespace

```
using Prism.DryIoc;

//Private and Public variables
public partial class App
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Actual Dry Ioc Container which can be called and used for manual registering and resolving dependencies.
    /// </summary>
    public static IContainer AppContainer { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use DryIoc container like below.

```
var authService = App.AppContainer.Resolve<IAuthenticationService>();//you need to register IAuthenticationService inside RegisterType Method.
```

> Note:- import DryIoc namespace in your class where you are calling
>   above line of code.

```
using DryIoc;
```

Happy Coding :)

> ***Note:- The above approach is not recommended as this will make your class / code untestable.***

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking to resolve the RestService dependency in ProfileService to make the network calls.

Never ever actively resolve anything anywhere, except once at the root of the application. (*)

What you want to do is to *inject* the dependency, i.e. you create a constructor parameter:

```
internal class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public ProfileService( IRestService restService )
    {
        // store restService for later, use it now... but have it injected, don't resolve it!
    }
}
```

(*) convention-over-registration stuff like the `ViewModelLocator` is a notable exception, but in fact, conceptionally, we inject a universal factory there more than resolving individual view models.

Comment: Hi Haukinger,  Thank you very much for the response. Actually, I tried that also but I couldn't get the instance of RestService using `IContainerRegistry` in `RegisterTypes` method.

Can you tell me how to get the instance of RestService in `RegisterTypes` method. I couldn't find any method like `containerRegistry.Resolve<T>()` or `containerRegistry.GetInstance<T>()`.

Comment: You don't need that. Register your services and you're done. Normally, it's a bad idea to resolve something in `RegisterTypes` (because you can never know whether all required registrations are completed already). You could use `GetContainer().Resolve()` but you better have a really good reason...